# Editing the CSS in Microsoft CRM 2013 - Where are the files located?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Our staff are having some issues using the new 2013 CRM.  Seems they can't handle the openness of the design, so I've been tasked with editing the CSS to basically add some borders to divs, tables, etc.

The problem I've run into is where are these files located?  The file names used when viewing the source appear to be dynamically generated, so I'm not sure where to go about editing anything.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Organization/_common/styles/main.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-177406624" id="/organization/_common/styles/main.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-177406624" />
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft CRM 2013 -- not the actual CSS issues.

Comment: This question is asking "how do i edit the CSS for MS CRM?" How could it be off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using something like the example shown at http://snataw.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/prettify-entity-form-in-crm-2013/ where you create a CSS style sheet as a Microsoft CRM web resource and then use JavaScript to load that web resource to override the default style that Microsoft CRM has.  I've used this for a few customer deployments, primarily for the word wrap functionality of the field display name labels, but I think it helps make the form look better with a nice box grid around the sub-grids and making the Header stand out a bit more than the default Microsoft CRM form.  This would be more supportable than making changes to any of the existing CRM files and also has the advantage that this method will work in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online environments where you do not have access to the underlying files in the CRM Server installation like you would in an OnPremise deployment.

Comment: This is a better method than trying to find and edit CSS files on the CRM server.  In addition to the benefits Chad listed this method can also be deployed as part of a CRM solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find *anything* about CRM 2013, but in Microsoft CRM 2011, the location appears to be **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb_common\styles\global.css** [(reference)](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/393281c6-2757-4829-8b38-71d9a6fc1783/identify-different-environments?forum=crm). It's likely/possible this file is in the same location in the 2013 version. (Sorry if you've checked there already, since the dynamic css file location points to a similar directory.)

Since information on this is quite scarce (it's unsupported by Microsoft and changes you make may get overwritten by future updates), here's another link mentioning "global.css.aspx": http://tntsharinglady.com/tag/global-css-aspx/